# How to set up SOAP client and server using php

Tags: php, web-services, soap

i have some problems with the soap client and soap server.

**server.php** on server side

```
class Server {
    public function hello($someone) {
        return "Hello ". $someone;
    }
}
$options= array('uri'=>'http://localhost/');
$server=new SoapServer(NULL, $options);
$server->setClass('Server');
$server->handle();
```

**index.php** on client side

```
<?php
$options = array('location' => 'http://localhost/server.php',
                    'uri' =>'http://localhost/');
$client = new SoapClient(NULL, $options);
echo $client->hello('Greg');
```

I'm testing this local on xampp and get the Error:
What do i make wrong ? Can i test it localy or do i have to set up a server for this. If yes, is it possible to run this on IIS ?

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
>   SoapClient->__doRequest('http://localhos...',
>   'http://localhos...', 1, 0) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\index.php(8):
>   SoapClient->__call('hello', Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\index.php(8): SoapClient->hello('Greg') #3 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\index.php on line 8

Comment: The above code works fine when I try it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PHP's soap server, but I do notice you're creating a variable called $test and then not doing anything with it.  Is $test what you're meant to be passing to $server->setClass()?

Comment: i looks like this is a xampp configuration issue @GordonM thank you i updated it but still get the error

Comment: @GordonM - It's enough to pass the class name to the `setClass()`-method like the OP does, so the `$test` variable, while not necessary, doesn't matter.

Comment: What happens if you try to access `http://localhost/server.php` directly?

Comment: I get a 404 error. Object not found. My port in xampp is localhost:8080

Comment: Aha. Then change the location to: `http://localhost:8080/server.php`

Comment: when i change it. I'm getting this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] DTD are not supported by SOAP in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\index.php(8): SoapClient->__call('hello', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\index.php(8): SoapClient->hello('Greg') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\index.php on line 8`

Comment: my soap drivers are enabled. The client and server driver

Comment: It's working the location path was wrong